# Calendar reminder does not work

Tags: release-hera, calendar

On elementary OS 5.1 Hera,when I configure a reminder in Calendar, it does not register. How can I fix this problem. I have not found any solution so far. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a known issue: (https://github.com/elementary/calendar/issues/459, https://github.com/elementary/calendar/issues/469, https://github.com/elementary/calendar/issues/474).

Edit: This should fix it: https://github.com/elementary/calendar/pull/481, hopefully it will be merged and then the fix will be provided in an update.